# Отсортировать массив по дате

Tags: javascript

Имею массив ar1, каждый элемент которого условно состоит из двух частей: 'msg' и 13_цифр - дата

```
ar1 = ["msg1601026412879","msg1601026416879","msg1601026415879","msg1601026414879","msg1601026413879"];
```

если хочу отсортировать по этой дате, то делаю так:

```
            let tst = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {tst.push(Number(ar1[i].slice(3)));};
            tst.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  }); // здесь сортирую цифры по возрастанию;
            ar1.length = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < tst.length; i++) {ar1.push('msg'+tst[i]);};
            Получаю отсортированный по дате:
            alert(ar1);
```

Как сделать правильно и максимально быстро (для большого числа элементов), если массив имеет вид:

```
ar2 = ["msg74185231601026412879","msg36547891601026416879","msg85296471601026415879","msg98752141601026414879","msg75315981601026413879"];
```

т.е. для ar2, каждый элемент которого состоит из трёх частей: 'msg' + 'рандом_7_цифр' + 13_цифр - дата?

UPD01: делал через объект, так:

```
ar1 = ["msg74185231601026412879","msg36547891601026416879","msg85296471601026415879","msg98752141601026414879","msg75315981601026413879"];

let tst = [];
let tmt = {};

for (let i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
     tst.push(Number(ar1[i].slice(10)));
     tmt[tst[i]] = ar1[i];
}

tst.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  }); // здесь сортирую цифры по возрастанию;

ar1.length = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < tst.length; i++) {
    ar1.push(tmt[tst[i]]);
}

alert(ar1);
```

Comment: Так а что мешает заменить в этом коде `slice(3)` на `slice(10)`?

Comment: @Yaant, делал через объект, - привёл в вопросе, думал есть проще, приведите, плиз, решение на slice(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let ar2 = ["msg74185231601026412879","msg36547891601026416879","msg85296471601026415879","msg98752141601026414879","msg75315981601026413879"];

ar2.sort((a, b) => a.slice(10) - b.slice(10));

console.log(ar2);
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас массив фиксированного формата (размера и структуры), поэтому не парьтесь и сравнивайте по строкам:

т.е. у вас каждый элемент называется msg***********************

а раз так, то полностью применимо обычное сравнение строк, в противном случае надо было бы выделять конечно целочисленные части и т.д.

**Typescript:**

```
let ar2: Array<string> = ar1.sort((a: string, b: string) => a.localeCompare(b));
```

**Javascipt:**

```
let ar2 = ar1.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
```